# HTML background url cached version of amazon S3 image

Tags: html, vue.js, amazon-s3, caching, background-image

In my application, I save image in a S3 bucket (AWS) that are basically the preview of a menu.It helps to display the "Thumbnail" of the menu and get an overview without having to enter it.
I actually update the image in S3 each time a change is made to the menu creator.

Then, if I check from the browser the url in S3, the image is well updated so the issue is not coming from s3 where the state of the image is the good one.

But in my application, where I use the url as "backgroundImage : url" the url don't get the latest version of the s3 image but the previous one (the one when we loaded the page first) .
If I refresh the page, then it's fine but it's seems like the background img has "cached" the image from the url and is not really live from the content in the s3 url.

Do you know if there is a way that the url can display in real time the content of my image in my S3 bucket and not just the state at first load ?

Here is the code in my client side that is in vueJs :

```js
 computed: {
    thumbnailStyles() {
      return {
        backgroundImage:`url(https://my-bucket.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/${this.menu.id})`,
        backgroundRepeat: 'round'
      }
    }
  },
```

```html
<div :style="thumbnailStyles"></div>
```

Thank you in advance and don't hesitate to ask more informations if it's not clear !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a paremeter in the url like `https://my-bucket.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/${this.menu.id}?ts=20220804-160000` where the ts is the date of the last change of image.

Comment: If I do so, it will not redirect the url to my s3 bucket value since the key will not correspond to the good one then, no ? 
Like how do i make the link, do you propose to create a new s3 image at each changes and to redirect it ?

Comment: Nope, i mean adding a parameter, that doesn't interfere to the resource link, in order to make your browser take it as new resource in order to cache the new changed image. But you should be able to know if the resource is changes or not.... Otherwise, if you don't care about browser caching your images, you could add a proper meta to ignore caching

Comment: I actually tried and it's working fine, a bit of delay due to aws time saving but it's working! Thank you !